# Memory allocation in Rust when using channels

Tags: rust

Recently I started playing with Rust. Trying to understand how it works. After Kotlin, Typescript and Go it become headache for me ) I wrote small app which reads messages from channel and wrote them into file. I receive unexpected for me memory usage. Code below. If anyone can explain me what I doing wrong, I will be very grateful.

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use std::io::{Write};
use std::fs::File;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use jemalloc_ctl::{stats, epoch};

const MSG_NUM: usize = 10000000;
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 1000;

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: jemallocator::Jemalloc = jemallocator::Jemalloc;

fn main() {

    let e = epoch::mib().unwrap();
    let allocated = stats::allocated::mib().unwrap();
    let resident = stats::resident::mib().unwrap();

    let (sender, receiver): (Sender<Vec<u8>>, Receiver<Vec<u8>>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (buffered_sender, buffered_receiver): (Sender<Vec<Message>>, Receiver<Vec<Message>>) = mpsc::channel();

    {
        for _ in 0..MSG_NUM {
            match sender.send(String::from("Hello World!").into_bytes()) {
                Ok(_) => continue,
                Err(err) => {
                    println!("Error {}", err);
                    continue
                },
            }
        }
        drop(sender)
    }

    e.advance().unwrap();
    println!("Step 1. {} MB allocated. {} MB resident", allocated.read().unwrap() / 1000000, resident.read().unwrap() / 1000000);

    {
        let mut buffer: Vec<Message> = Vec::new();

        loop {

            let next_msg = match receiver.recv() {
                Ok(msg) => msg,
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("Channel closed for \"receiver\".");
                    break;
                }
            };

            buffer.push(Message {bytes: next_msg});

            if buffer.len() == BUFFER_SIZE {
                match buffered_sender.send(buffer.clone()) {
                    Ok(_) => {},
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("Error: {}", err);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                buffer.clear()
            }
        }

        drop(buffered_sender);
    };

    e.advance().unwrap();
    println!("Step 2. Excpected to see same amount of memory like in Step 1, but was: {} MB allocated. {} MB resident", allocated.read().unwrap() / 1000000, resident.read().unwrap() / 1000000);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut file = OpenOptions::new().create(true).append(true).open("foo.txt").unwrap();

        loop {
            match buffered_receiver.recv() {
                Ok(messages) => {
                    on_msg(messages, &mut file);
                },
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("Channel closed for \"buffered_receiver\".");
                    break;
                }
            };
        }

        e.advance().unwrap();
        println!("Step 3. Excpected to see around 0 MB allocated, but was: {} MB allocated. {} MB resident", allocated.read().unwrap() / 1000000, resident.read().unwrap() / 1000000);
    });

    loop {

    }
}

fn on_msg(buffer: Vec<Message>, file: &mut File) {
    let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    for msg in buffer.iter() {
        bytes.extend(msg.bytes.iter());
    }
    let _ = file.write(&*bytes); 
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Message {
    bytes: Vec<u8>
}
```

Execution result:

```
Step 1. 640 MB allocated. 653 MB resident
Channel closed for "receiver".
Step 2. Excpected to see same amount of memory like in Step 1, but was: 886 MB allocated. 942 MB resident
Channel closed for "buffered_receiver".
Step 3. Excpected to see around 0 MB allocated, but was: 480 MB allocated. 880 MB resident
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete: it's missing steps 2 and 3

Comment: Receivers are alive, but all messages from channels were read. In my understanding at the end of program should be 2 empty channels

Comment: @stam112814 converted my comment to a response: that the channel is empty doesn't mean it's been shrunk (let alone deallocated). And if they don't shrink (which seems to be the case after testing dropping them) all the memory it's reserved when you filled them up would still be sitting around the same way an emptied vec or deque still has all the memory allocated ready to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You're only dropping the "sender" sides of your channels, and I'd expect most of the buffering to occur on the receiver side since sending never fails and you can recv() after having closed the channel.

Running your original script, I get this:

```
Step 1. 640 MB allocated. 652 MB resident
Channel closed for "receiver".
Step 2. Excpected to see same amount of memory like in Step 1, but was: 886 MB allocated. 943 MB resident
Channel closed for "buffered_receiver".
Step 3. Excpected to see around 0 MB allocated, but was: 480 MB allocated. 943 MB resident
```

modifying the script to drop the receivers (`receiver` at the same time as `buffered_sender` and `buffered_receiver` at the end of the read thread but before advancing the epoch) I get:

```
Step 1. 640 MB allocated. 652 MB resident
Channel closed for "receiver".
Step 2. Excpected to see same amount of memory like in Step 1, but was: 406 MB allocated. 943 MB resident
Channel closed for "buffered_receiver".
Step 3. Excpected to see around 0 MB allocated, but was: 0 MB allocated. 943 MB resident
```

Incidentally *crossbeam channels* (which are usually considered superior to the stdlib's on every point) seem to behave as you were expecting, converting the script to them (which also allows simplifying it as crossbeam channels can be iterated) I get:

```
Step 1. 490 MB allocated. 508 MB resident
Channel closed for "receiver".
Step 2. Excpected to see same amount of memory like in Step 1, but was: 406 MB allocated. 790 MB resident
Channel closed for "buffered_receiver".
Step 3. Excpected to see around 0 MB allocated, but was: 0 MB allocated. 790 MB resident
```

Comment: In this script I want to check how channels using memory in case when receiver always alive. I don't want to close receiver, because it always should listen for incoming messages.

Comment: Well then the answer for the stdlib library's MPSC channels seem "however much was necessary to reach the high-water mark" because apparently they don't release memory from that. Though you may want to ask people in charge of mpsc on one of the "official" channels to make sure.

Comment: Yes, crossbeam channels looks better than MPSC. But again not all memory released. Activity Monitor shows 390MB of used memory in the end of my script.

PS. There is no answer from "official" channel )

Comment: @Masklinn, could you add the crossbeam solution to your answer?... Or is the api the exact same?

Comment: @richardpringle it is the same API aside from the imports, and the creation function being called [unbounded](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/0.4.0/crossbeam_channel/fn.unbounded.html) rather than `channel`.